# Displaying an ACF field via `woocommerce_view_order`

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I have created a custom field in my order with the ACF plugin. The field contains a tracking code and is stored under `_tracking_code`.

I am trying to display the tracking code via the `woocommerce_view_order` action hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'order_page', 30 );
function order_page() {
    echo get_field('tracking_code'); // ACF Custom Field
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `woocommerce_view_order` hook gives you the order ID to work with. So you could do something like this"

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'add_custom_tracking_field', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_tracking_field( $order_id ) {
    if ( $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ) {
        if ( !empty( $order->get_meta( 'tracking_code' ) ) ) {
            printf( 'Tracking code: %s', $order->get_meta( 'tracking_code' ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the lovely support. Just a minor update please add ")" ( $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ) ")" and printf

Comment: No problem. Typos fixed, answer updated. Thank you for pointing those out.